# How to change MUI Select field perimeter color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, colors, material-ui

[image]

This is an MUI select box. Its color is blue when selected, but black when it isn't. I want the text and boundary to be white (currently blue). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code with styled component

".Mui-focused": {
color: #FFF,
},// for name/label

".MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
borderColor: #FFF
},